# How can I trace an image to create an object?

Tags: mesh

For reference material, I've loaded an image onto a plane and made it un-selectable. Now I'd like to "trace" it by clicking to create a series of vertices, make them into a path, turn that path into a plane, then extrude the plane into a 3D shape. (In Photoshop terms, I'd like to use the Blender equivalent of the Polygonal Lasso tool to create and fill a selection with color.)

So far, I've been doing this by adding a plane, then subdividing and pushing around individual vertices until I have enough to approximate my reference. It's a slow process and it strikes me that there's likely a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hit <kbd>e</kbd> to extrude a vertex or you can <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + right click to extrude to mouse position. <kbd>F</kbd> while two vertices are selected will join them with an edge, and if you have an edge loop selected the same <kbd>f</kbd> will fill it with a face.

Comment: This is very basic functionality and this question is probably not very valuable for BSE community. It might be easier for you to see some tutorials [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6) that will answer all the basic questions like that quickly and more efficiently than it would be to ask them on Blender Stack Exchange.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: There might be nothing wrong with it. But it's far more efficient to just watch a few tutorials to get the basic stuff out of the way. If you hover the mouse over the downvote arrow, the tootltip says: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Does this question show any research effort?..