# How can I cut a plane in irregular way?

Tags: image, shape-keys

I'm trying to do a happy birthday video for a friend, he is a fan of How I Met your mother, and my hope is to make a nice remake of the main intro, with pictures of our group of friends. The first thing that I noticed is that *the shapes of the main characters are cut as in collage*.

I don't know how I can cut the plane irregularly following the shapes of people in a photo.
**LEGEN** ... waiting for your suggestions ...**DARY**
If you need, you can watch the intro here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DUV2oAL11A

Comment: Trace the image in a vector drawing program, like Inkscape or Illustrator, then bring 
 the image as SVG to blender. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52563/how-do-i-turn-my-png-image-into-a-mesh-object/52564#52564 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53910/how-to-inset-or-fill-in-a-complicated-mesh/53940#53940

Comment: Or trace the image directly in blender (not t though that blender's tools to manipulate curves are quite rudimentary). https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58626/is-it-possible-to-import-the-outline-or-profile-of-something-from-a-picture-to-u/58630#58630 but you can do this as a regular mesh as well, by creating connected vertices and then closing the shape with faces. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154032/how-can-i-trace-an-image-to-create-an-object

Comment: Or import the image as reference and use the Grease Pencil to trace the image, then convert it to a curve or a mesh.

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183131/any-suggestions-on-how-to-model-it-i-tried-few-but-couldnt-find-the-perfect-on/183515#183515

Comment: @susu  + bl4nk .. deleted my start at an answer - it would have duplicated  susu's recommendations .

Comment: @RobinBetts I'll delete my lazy comments... (i don't feel like writing a concrete answer), so please don't delete yours! Comments are not answers...

Comment: @susu They're fine! I would leave them! We don't want duplicated answers..

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take some time to check all of your suggestions

Comment: I have followed the first one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52563/how-do-i-turn-my-png-image-into-a-mesh-object/52564#52564 but when i Import the SVG, there are many holes in it and i don't know how to apply the texture of the picture @susu, do you have some suggestion?

Comment: Holes? Without a picture is hard to understand. Watch for overlapping or disconeected segments on the path.